# VBA: Set variable to "Empty" or "Missing"? Handling multiple optional arguments?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Is it possible, or desirable, to set objects/data to an "Empty" or "Missing" variant?
I want to be able to conditionally pass optional arguments to a function. Sometimes I want to use an optional argument, sometimes I don't.

In Python, you could easily pass through whichever optional arguments you wanted by using **kwdargs to unpack a dictionary or list into your function arguments. Is there something similar (or a way to hack it in VBA) so you can pass in Empty/Missing optional arguments?

In particular, I'm trying to use *Application.Run* with an arbitrary number of arguments.

**EDIT**:

I'm basically trying to do this:

```
Public Function bob(Optional arg1 = 0, Optional arg2 = 0, Optional arg3 = 0, Optional arg4 = 0)
    bob = arg1 + arg2 + arg3 + arg4
End Function

Public Function joe(Optional arg1)
    joe = arg1 * 4
End Function


Public Sub RunArbitraryFunctions()
    'Run a giant list of arbitrary functions pseudocode

    Dim flist(1 To 500)
    flist(1) = "bob"
    flist(2) = "joe"
    flist(3) = "more arbitrary functions of arbitrary names"
    flist(N) = ".... and so on"

    Dim arglist1(1 To 4)        'arguments for bob
    Dim arglist2(1 To 1)        'arguments for joe 
    Dim arglist3(1 To M number of arguments for each ith function)


    For i = 1 To N
        'Execute Application.Run,
        'making sure the right number of arguments are passed in somehow.
        'It'd also be nice if there was a way to automatically unpack arglisti
        Application.Run flist(i) arglisti(1), arglisti(2), arglisti(3), ....
    Next i

End Sub
```

Because the number of arguments changes for each function call, what is the acceptable way to make sure the right number of inputs are input into Application.Run?

The equivalent Python code would be

```
funclist = ['bob', 'joe', 'etc']
arglists = [[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,2,3,4,5], etc]

for args, funcs in zip(arglists, funclist):
    func1 = eval(funcs)
    output = func1(*args)
```

Comment: there is a function in VBA called IsMissing() for evaluate optional arguments http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251721(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I am not entirely sure this is what you are looking for, but have you checked [ParamArray](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1005%20ParamArray.shtml)? It is of `Variant` type, and you can check if it is empty, and takes an arbitrary number of elements.

Comment: In addition to ParamArray You can also use the Optional keyword, and, in addition, optionally set a default value; depending on the type of variable, you could test by either IsMissing; Is Nothing; IsEmpty (if you optionally set a Variant to empty), etc.

Comment: @Ron Thanks your comment is exactly what I needed. I had no idea you could do something like: b = Empty

Answer (score 1):

in *VBA* you use **ParamArray** to enter option inputs to functions.

See  [Pearson Material](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/OptionalArgumentsToProcedures.aspx)

Comment: +1. ParamArray is the closest to `Python`'s `kwargs` (although it is not a dictionary).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways in which a routine can change the number of arguments that has to be provided to it:

- declare some of the trailing arguments as [`Optional`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/optional-parameters)
- declare the last argument as [`ParamArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/parameter-arrays)

A single routine can use either or both.

---

An `Optional` parameter may have a strict type (e.g. `Optional s As String`), but then it will be impossible to detect whether it was passed. If you don't pass a value for such argument, the correct flavour of "blank" will be used, which is indistinguishable from passing that blank value manually.
So, having `Public Sub Bob(Optional S As String)`, you cannot detect from inside of `Bob` whether it was called as `Bob` or as `Bob vbNullString`.
An optional parameter may have a default value, which suffers from the same problem. So, having `Public Sub Bob(Optional S As String = "Default Value")`, you cannot detect if `Bob` was called as `Bob` or as `Bob "Default Value"`.

To be able to truly detect whether an optional parameter was passed, they have to be typed as `Variant`. Then a special function, [`IsMissing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ismissing-function), can be used inside the routine to detect if a parameter was passed.

```vb
Public Sub Bob(Optional a, Optional b, Optional c, Optional d)
    Debug.Print IsMissing(a), IsMissing(b), IsMissing(c), IsMissing(d)
End Sub
```

```vb
Bob 1, , 3  ' Prints False, True, False, True
```

---

`ParamArray` can only be the last argument, and it allows an infinite* number of arguments to be passed starting from this position. All these arguments arrive packed in a single `Variant` array (no option for static typing here).

The `IsMissing` function does not work on the `ParamArray` argument (always returns False). The way to know how many arguments were passed is to compare `UBound(args)` with `LBound(args)`. Note that this only tells you how many argument "slots" were used, but some of them can be in fact missing!

```vb
Public Sub BobArray(ParamArray a())
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        Debug.Print IsMissing(a(i)), ;
    Next
    Debug.Print
End Sub
```

```vb
BobArray                 ' Prints empty line (the For loop is not entered due to UBound < LBound)
Sheet1.BobArray 1, 2, 3  ' Prints False, False, False
Sheet1.BobArray 1, , 3   ' Prints False, True, False
```

Note that you cannot pass "missing" value for the trailing arguments of the `ParamArray`, i.e. this is illegal:

```vb
Sheet1.BobArray 1, , 3,   ' Does not compile
```

However, you *can* work around this using the trick described below.

---

An interesting use case that you touch in your question is preparing an array of all arguments in advance, passing it to the function, filling all the arguments "placeholders", but still expecting the function to detect that some of the arguments are missing (not passed).

Normally this is not possible, because if anything is passed (even "blank" values, such as `Empty`, `Null`, `Nothing` of `vbNullString`), then it still counts as passed, and `IsMissing()` will return `False`.

Fortunately, the special `Missing` value is nothing but a specially constructed `Variant`, and even without knowing how to construct that value manually, we can trick the compiler to give it away:

```vb
Public Function GetMissingValue(Optional ByVal IgnoreMe As Variant) As Variant
    If IsMissing(IgnoreMe) Then
        GetMissingValue = IgnoreMe
    Else
        Err.Raise 5, , "I told you to ignore me, didn't I"
    End If
End Function
```

```vb
Dim missing As Variant
missing = GetMissingValue()

Dim arglist1(1 To 4) As Variant
arglist1(1) = 42
arglist1(2) = missing
arglist1(3) = missing
arglist1(4) = "!"

Bob arglist1(1), arglist1(2), arglist1(3), arglist1(4)   ' Prints False, True, True, False
```

Now, we can work around the inability to pass "missing" to the trailing "slots" of `ParamArray`:

```vb
Dim arglist1(1 To 4) As Variant
arglist1(1) = 42
arglist1(2) = missing
arglist1(3) = missing
arglist1(4) = missing

BobArray arglist1(1), arglist1(2), arglist1(3), arglist1(4) ' Prints False, True, True, True
```

Note, however, that this workaround will only work if you call `BobArray` directly. If you use `Application.Run`, it will not work because the `Run` method will discard any trailing "missing" arguments before passing them onto the called routine:

```vb
Dim arglist1(1 To 4) As Variant
arglist1(1) = 42
arglist1(2) = missing
arglist1(3) = missing
arglist1(4) = missing

Application.Run "BobArray", arglist1(1), arglist1(2), arglist1(3), arglist1(4)
' Prints False, because only one argument is passed
```

Answer (score 1):

Further to @GSerg's very comprehensive answer (I don't have enough reputation just to comment), the 'special' value assigned to a Missing argument has the 'appearance' of being an Error value - it converts to "Error 448" (Named argument not found) using `CStr()`, and responds to `IsError()` as `TRUE`. However, an attempt to preset the argument using `CvErr(448)` before passing to a procedure (in the hope that it will be recognised as Missing) fails, perhaps because the value is 'not quite' the same as the Error value in some way.

@GSerg suggested a method of 'recording' the value actually passed by the compiler when an argument is missing and using that to preset a dummy argument prior to passing to the procedure needing to be fooled. This method, indeed, does work and I have simply extended @GSerg's function to replace his error message (if it is inadvertently called with an argument) by a recursive call without an argument which ensures a successful outcome either way. Usage is simply to preset the dummy variable(s) before passing to a procedure (where it/they will then be treated as missing): `Dummy_Var = Missing()`.

```
Public Function Missing(Optional ByVal X As Variant) As Variant
    
    If IsMissing(X) Then    'correctly called
        Missing = X
    Else                    'bad user call
        Missing = Missing() 'recursive call (no arg!)
    End If

End Function
```

I have just done a quick trial with `Application.Run`. Early embedded 'missing' arguments (ie, followed by 'normal' ones) appear to be successfully registered as 'missing' in the called procedure. So, too, however, are final trailing 'missing' arguments - whether actually passed by the `Run` method, or truncated (as suggested by @GSerg), but still filled in by the compiler as genuinely missing.

Interestingly, and usefully (to a niche market), additional 'missing' arguments (beyond those defined by the procedure) appear to be tolerated by the compiler *without* generating the 'Wrong number of arguments' message associated with extra 'normal' arguments. This opens up the possibility of procedure calls using `Application.Run` (when a variable number of arguments is desired) being implemented by a single universal call (with up to 30 arguments if necessary) padded out with fake 'missing' arguments instead of having to provided several alternative calls of different lengths and/or argument configurations to cope with exact procedure definitions.

Answer (score 0):

So addressing the question of optionally using arguments it looks like my question in [Calling vba macro from python with unknown number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188684/calling-vba-macro-from-python-with-unknown-number-of-arguments), check it out accordingly.

Hence:
**Using Python**:

```py
def run_vba_macro(str_path, str_modulename, str_macroname, **kwargs):
    if os.path.exists(str_path):
        xl=win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
        wb=xl.Workbooks.Open(str_path, ReadOnly=0)
        xl.Visible = True
        if kwargs:
                params_for_excel = list(kwargs.values())
                xl.Application.Run(os.path.basename(str_path)+"!"+str_modulename+'.'+str_macroname,
                                          *params_for_excel,)
        else:
                xl.Application.Run(os.path.basename(str_path)
                                          +"!"+str_modulename
                                          +'.'+str_macroname)
        wb.Close(SaveChanges=0)
        xl.Application.Quit()
        del xl

#example
kwargs={'str_file':r'blablab'}
run_vba_macro(r'D:\arch_v14.xlsm',
              str_modulename="Module1",
              str_macroname='macro1',
              **kwargs)
#other example
kwargs={'arg1':1,'arg2':2}
run_vba_macro(r'D:\arch_v14.xlsm',
              str_modulename="Module1",
              str_macroname='macro_other',
              **kwargs)
```

**Using VBA**:

```
Sub macro1(ParamArray args() as Variant)
    MsgBox("success the str_file argument was passed as =" & args(0))
End Sub

Sub macro_other(ParamArray args() as Variant)
    MsgBox("success the arguments have passed as =" & str(args(0)) & " and " & str(args(1)))
End Sub
```

Also another use case only using VBA is here for reference. It is a question that has not been answered and is around for long, although recently it was updated by the community server automatically with some good ideas related links accordingly.

Here is an answer you can do it if you use this:

```
Sub pass_one()
    Call flexible("a")
End Sub
Sub pass_other()
    Call flexible("a", 2)
End Sub
Sub flexible(ParamArray args() As Variant)
    Dim i As Long
    MsgBox ("I have received " & _
            Str(UBound(args) + 1) & _
            " parameters.")
    For i = 0 To UBound(args)
        MsgBox (TypeName(args(i)))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Only for developers that also use Python: 
If you are using Python's kwargs, simply starr expression and pass a Python tuple.
Here it is (it is related with my question in [Calling vba macro from python with unknown number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188684/calling-vba-macro-from-python-with-unknown-number-of-arguments))
Cheers.

Comment: `that has not been answered` - what about the [answer from 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26025483/11683) that discusses exactly the same thing (which is not quite what the OP wanted, as far as I can tell)?

Comment: @GSerg ok thanks, have edited it and now hopefully it improved, only if a little. cheers.

Comment: The OP does not mention using Excel from python, they only mention python as an example of what happens when calling a routine with variable number of arguments, otherwise they are working in VBA. I also do not think there is ever a need to post anyone's *question* as an answer.

Comment: Hmm, the User asked for "I want to be able to conditionally pass optional arguments to a function. Sometimes I want to use an optional argument, sometimes I don't." And he was familiar with python so i gave a working example of using it with Python, and another only with VBA. Also it was not the question because the code has changed a bit so it is working. Again it's ok if this does not add information i can ask for delete, although in my opinion it adds a full working solution. Either way it is ok, Cheers.