# How to apply the IsMissing function?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel Version 1902, Build 11328.20392 within MS Office 365 ProPlus.

I call a function from a cell in a worksheet:

```
=addOnlyPositiveValues(D2, E2, F2,G2)
```

Only the first parameter is mandatory, the others are optional:

```vb
Function addOnlyPositiveValues(v01 As Range, Optional v02 As Range, Optional v03 As Range, Optional v04 As Range, Optional v05 As Range ) As Double
    Dim dblRet                  As Double
    dblRet = 0
    dblRet = var2dbl_positiveOnly(v01.Value)
    If Not (IsMissing(v02)) Then dblRet = dblRet + var2dbl_positiveOnly(CVar(v02.Value))
    If Not (IsMissing(v03)) Then dblRet = dblRet + var2dbl_positiveOnly(CVar(v03.Value))
    If Not (IsMissing(v04)) Then dblRet = dblRet + var2dbl_positiveOnly(CVar(v04.Value))
    If Not (IsMissing(v05)) Then dblRet = dblRet + var2dbl_positiveOnly(CVar(v05.Value))

'    If Not (IsMissing(v05) Or (v05 Is Nothing)) Then dblRet = dblRet + var2dbl_positiveOnly(CVar(v05.Value))

    addOnlyPositiveValues = dblRet
End Function
```

This worked until recently (can't tell exactly when it starting to act up).
In my example above I don't set a 5th parameter.
I expect the function to skip the `If Not (IsMissing(v05)) Then ...`. Stepping through the code I see that `v05` is `NOTHING`.

My workaround:

```vb
If Not (IsMissing(v05) Or (v05 Is Nothing)) Then ...
```

Comment: In case you want to look into another option for your function with unsure number of parameters: the ParamArray is a nice option.

Answer (score 7):

`Optional` parameters [only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58191292/11683) make sense when they are declared as `Variant`. Only a `Variant` can contain the special value `Variant/Missing` that the `IsMissing` function detects.

Your parameters are `Range`s, so when not filled in, they contain `Nothing`, and `IsMissing` is always going to be `False` for them.

That code could never work with `IsMissing`. If it did, then the parameters were declared as `Variant`, either explicitly (`As Variant`) or implicitly (by omitting the type completely).

Comment: very good explanation!

I had the parameters expl. declared as variants once but it didn't work anymore from one day to the other, stalling the whole application. I have no clue why that was but tracing lead to the workaround with ranges and 'Is Nothing'. I fell back to variants now and it works just fine.