# Pass arguments to a worksheet function as an array in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a VBA function that calls the SUMIFS worksheet function. It works perfectly but I would like to get rid of the Select statement. That requires that the `Criteria range` and `Criteria` argument pairs, nominally unlimited in number, be passed to SUMIFS as one array which is assembled in the function.

Here is my current code.

```
Function SUMIFS(SumRng As Range, _
                ParamArray Ifs() As Variant) As Double
    ' each element of Ifs is an array of 3 elements:
    '   0 = Criteria range, 1 = Operator, 2 = Criterium

    Const Symbols   As String = "=,<>,>,<,<=,>="
    
    Dim Symb()      As String
    Dim Tmp         As Variant
    Dim i           As Long             ' Ifs index
    
    Symb = Split(Symbols, ",")
    For i = LBound(Ifs) To UBound(Ifs)
        Tmp = Ifs(i)(1)
        If VarType(Ifs(i)(2)) = vbDate Then
            Ifs(i)(1) = Format(Ifs(i)(2), Ifs(i)(0).Cells(1).NumberFormat)
        Else
            Ifs(i)(1) = Ifs(i)(2)
        End If
        If Val(Tmp) Then Ifs(i)(1) = Symb(Tmp) & Ifs(i)(1)
    Next i
    
    Select Case UBound(Ifs)
        Case 0
            SUMIFS = WorksheetFunction.SUMIFS(SumRng, Ifs(0)(0), Ifs(0)(1))
        Case 1
            SUMIFS = WorksheetFunction.SUMIFS(SumRng, Ifs(0)(0), Ifs(0)(1), _
                                                      Ifs(1)(0), Ifs(1)(1))
        Case 2
            SUMIFS = WorksheetFunction.SUMIFS(SumRng, Ifs(0)(0), Ifs(0)(1), _
                                                      Ifs(1)(0), Ifs(1)(1), _
                                                      Ifs(2)(0), Ifs(2)(1))
        Case 3
            SUMIFS = WorksheetFunction.SUMIFS(SumRng, Ifs(0)(0), Ifs(0)(1), _
                                                      Ifs(1)(0), Ifs(1)(1), _
                                                      Ifs(2)(0), Ifs(2)(1), _
                                                      Ifs(3)(0), Ifs(3)(1))
        Case 4
            SUMIFS = WorksheetFunction.SUMIFS(SumRng, Ifs(0)(0), Ifs(0)(1), _
                                                      Ifs(1)(0), Ifs(1)(1), _
                                                      Ifs(2)(0), Ifs(2)(1), _
                                                      Ifs(3)(0), Ifs(3)(1), _
                                                      Ifs(4)(0), Ifs(4)(1))
    End Select
End Function
```

Note that the operator is passed to this function as a number (enum) between 0 and 5 which specifies one of the elements of `Symb()`.

As you see, there are 4 different function calls in this procedure and if the function were to be called with 5 criteria pairs it would fail. Meanwhile, the differences between the 4 calls are minute and systematic, and a fifth one could be added in a minute.

I'm looking for a way to pass an assembled array of arguments to a single call of the worksheet function. I know this is possible by creating the corresponding worksheet function string and using the `Evaluate` function but when I write worksheet functions in VBA they turn out messy, meaning they are difficult to maintain and evolve. I like the clear structure of my above code and wouldn't like to sacrifice it for a little more efficiency, meaning I am open to arguments of much greater efficiency or pleasing design, whichever might be on offer.

### EDIT 20 Jan 2021

I thought I had a solution with @GSerg's idea but the function call only accepts 2 sets of criteria. It doesn't seem to make sense because the third criterium is created in just the same way as the second. I'm wondering if I've become blind to a simple flaw. Please take a look.

```
Private Sub Test_SUMIFS()
    Dim SumRng As Range
    
    Set SumRng = Range("A2:A11")
    Debug.Print SUMIFS(SumRng, Array(Range("B2:B11"), 0, "A"))
    Debug.Print SUMIFS(SumRng, Array(Range("B2:B11"), 0, "A"), _
                               Array(Range("C2:C11"), 0, 10))
'    Debug.Print SUMIFS(SumRng, Array(Range("B2:B11"), 0, "A"), _
'                               Array(Range("C2:C11"), 0, 10), _
'                               Array(Range("D2:D11"), 0, "Z"))
End Sub

Function SUMIFS(SumRng As Range, _
                ParamArray Ifs() As Variant) As Double
    ' each element of Ifs is an array of 3 elements:
    '   0 = Criteria range, 1 = Operator, 2 = Criterium

    Const Symbols   As String = "=,<>,>,<,<=,>="
    
    Dim Symb()      As String
    Dim Fun()       As Variant          ' Converterd Ifs()
    Dim Tmp         As Variant
    Dim i           As Long             ' Ifs index
    
    ReDim Fun(2, 1)                     ' extend to a maximum of 14 if required
    Symb = Split(Symbols, ",")
    For i = LBound(Ifs) To 1
        If i > UBound(Ifs) Then
            Fun(i, 0) = SetMissing()
            Fun(i, 1) = SetMissing()
        Else
            Set Fun(i, 0) = Ifs(i)(0)
            Fun(i, 1) = Ifs(i)(2)
            Tmp = Ifs(i)(1)
            If VarType(Ifs(i)(2)) = vbDate Then
                Fun(i)(1) = Format(Ifs(i)(2), Ifs(i)(0).Cells(1).NumberFormat)
            Else
                Fun(i, 1) = Ifs(i)(2)
            End If
            If Val(Tmp) Then Fun(i)(1) = Symb(Tmp) & Fun(i)(1)
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' this function call works for both calls
    SUMIFS = WorksheetFunction.SUMIFS(SumRng, Fun(0, 0), Fun(0, 1), _
                                              Fun(1, 0), Fun(1, 1))
    ' this function call doesn't work
'    SUMIFS = WorksheetFunction.SUMIFS(SumRng, Fun(0, 0), Fun(0, 1), _
'                                              Fun(1, 0), Fun(1, 1), _
'                                              Fun(2, 0), Fun(2, 1))
End Function

Private Function SetMissing(Optional ByVal MissingValue As Variant) As Variant
    ' assign the value of "Missing" to an uninitialized variant
    
    If IsMissing(MissingValue) Then
        SetMissing = MissingValue
    Else
        Err.Raise 5, , "Wrong use of function: The parameter must be missing!"
    End If
End Function
```

If you run the code as it is it will work once the test ranges have been set up in the ActiveSheet, but not with the second worksheet function call.

Comment: How do you call the function, please? What elements do you have in 'ParamArray()' ? If smells at jagged array, but how do you  build it? With the exactly `SumIfs` parameters, separated by comma, too?

Comment: @FaneDuru From the use of it, it must be `SUMIFS(Me.Range("A1:A10"), Array(Me.Range("B1:B10"), 2), Array(Me.Range("C1:C10"), 3))`. However the exact way this function is called is not really important for answering the question of how to pass it along to `SumIfs`.

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks for the response. I was without Internet for 2 days. So, sorry for the late response but I can't add to what GSerg already said :-)

Comment: No problem. I shouldn't ask that question if I would read the question being more focused... I initially understood that the way of passing the variables does not work and tried to understand if it's a matter of wrong parameters. Otherwise, the parameters could be only in the way GSerg suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> argument pairs, nominally unlimited in number

Actually, you can pass up to 14 pairs of ranges to `SumIfs`, as there are only 29 arguments. These Excel functions are normally limited to 30 arguments, adding the 15th pair would push the argument count to 31. So you can hardcode a `Select Case` for the 14 cases and call it day, it won't grow.

---

Another option is to manually pass the [`Missing` value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58191292/11683) for the missing arguments:

```vb
Public Function GetMissingValue(Optional ByVal IgnoreMe As Variant) As Variant
    If IsMissing(IgnoreMe) Then
        GetMissingValue = IgnoreMe
    Else
        Err.Raise 5, , "I told you to ignore me, didn't I"
    End If
End Function
```

```vb
Dim missing As Variant
missing = GetMissingValue()

...

Dim Args(0 To 13, 0 To 1) As Variant
Dim i As Long
  
For i = LBound(Ifs) To UBound(Ifs)
    Set Args(i, 0) = Ifs(i)(0)
    Args(i, 1) = Ifs(i)(1)
Next
  
For i = UBound(Ifs) + 1 To UBound(Args)
    Args(i, 0) = missing
    Args(i, 1) = missing
Next
  
SUMIFS = Application.WorksheetFunction.SUMIFS(SumRng, Args(0, 0), Args(0, 1), _
                                                      Args(1, 0), Args(1, 1), _
                                                      Args(2, 0), Args(2, 1), _
                                                      Args(3, 0), Args(3, 1), _
                                                      Args(4, 0), Args(4, 1), _
                                                      Args(5, 0), Args(5, 1), _
                                                      Args(6, 0), Args(6, 1), _
                                                      Args(7, 0), Args(7, 1), _
                                                      Args(8, 0), Args(8, 1), _
                                                      Args(9, 0), Args(9, 1), _
                                                      Args(10, 0), Args(10, 1), _
                                                      Args(11, 0), Args(11, 1), _
                                                      Args(12, 0), Args(12, 1), _
                                                      Args(13, 0), Args(13, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry for my late reply. This looks exactly like what I was looking for - plus the extra information about the capacity - provided I understand correctly that overload arguments can be passed as "missing". I'll test that idea in the morning.

Comment: The solution I constructed using your idea got stuck half way. It seems to me that my solution isn't any different from yours, or is it? Please look at the edit in my question.

Comment: @Variatus The `Args` must be `0 To 13` at all times. You are always passing all 29 arguments to `SUMIFS`. In your edit, you must have `ReDim Fun(13, 1)` and the loop must be `For i = 0 to 13`, not `For i = LBound(Ifs) To 1`.

Comment: Yes, of course. Thank you. In the light of morning - and with your pointer - I saw the error immediately. It wasn't at the highlight but in the array. However, your statement that all 13 arguments must be supplied isn't correct. Therefore I shall post another answer.

Answer (score 0):

The function below can be called with a one to a maximum of 7 pairs of *Criteria Range* and *Criterium*. This limit can be extended to 13, requiring only a single change in the code at `Redim Fun(7, 1)` and addition of the extra arguments in the function call.

```
Function SUMIFS(SumRng As Range, _
                ParamArray Ifs() As Variant) As Double
    ' each element of Ifs is an array of 3 elements:
    '   0 = Criteria range, 1 = Operator, 2 = Criterium

    Const Symbols   As String = "=,<>,>,<,<=,>="
    
    Dim Symb()      As String
    Dim Fun()       As Variant          ' Converterd Ifs()
    Dim Tmp         As Variant
    Dim i           As Long             ' Ifs index
    
    ReDim Fun(7, 1)                     ' extend to a maximum of 13 if required
    Symb = Split(Symbols, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(Fun)
        If i > UBound(Ifs) Then
            Fun(i, 0) = SetMissing()
            Fun(i, 1) = SetMissing()
        Else
            Set Fun(i, 0) = Ifs(i)(0)
            Fun(i, 1) = Ifs(i)(2)
            Tmp = Ifs(i)(1)
            If VarType(Ifs(i)(2)) = vbDate Then
                Fun(i)(1) = CLng(Ifs(i)(2))
            Else
                Fun(i, 1) = Ifs(i)(2)
            End If
            If Val(Tmp) Then Fun(i)(1) = Symb(Tmp) & Fun(i)(1)
        End If
    Next i
    
    SUMIFS = WorksheetFunction.SUMIFS(SumRng, Fun(0, 0), Fun(0, 1), _
                                              Fun(1, 0), Fun(1, 1), _
                                              Fun(2, 0), Fun(2, 1), _
                                              Fun(3, 0), Fun(3, 1), _
                                              Fun(4, 0), Fun(4, 1), _
                                              Fun(5, 0), Fun(5, 1), _
                                              Fun(6, 0), Fun(6, 1), _
                                              Fun(7, 0), Fun(7, 1)) ', _
'                                              Fun(8, 0), Fun(8, 1), _
'                                              Fun(9, 0), Fun(9, 1), _
'                                              Fun(10, 0), Fun(10, 1), _
'                                              Fun(11, 0), Fun(11, 1), _
'                                              Fun(12, 0), Fun(12, 1), _
'                                              Fun(13, 0), Fun(13, 1))
End Function
```

In fact, the function call may be expanded to a number of arguments greater than *Ubound(Fun)* but not greater than 13, somewhat validating @GSerg's assertion that the total number (including the sum range) must be below 30.

I reformulated GSerg's supporting function that converts a non-existent argument to a "missing" one to match my method of understanding. It's functionality couldn't be improved but I prefer to keep it private since it's the slave of this one function.

```
Private Function SetMissing(Optional ByVal MissingValue As Variant) As Variant
    ' assign an uninitialized variant to "MissingValue"
    
    If IsMissing(MissingValue) Then
        SetMissing = MissingValue
    Else
        Err.Raise 5, , "Wrong use of function: The parameter must be missing!"
    End If
End Function
```

Below is the procedure for testing my function, calling it with 1, 2 and 3 criteria. Note that the `0` argument specifies the first of the operators in `Const Symbols`. It therefore couldn't be a number greater than 5.

```
Private Sub Test_SUMIFS()
    Dim SumRng As Range
    
    Set SumRng = Range("A2:A11")
    Debug.Print SUMIFS(SumRng, Array(Range("B2:B11"), 0, "A"))
    Debug.Print SUMIFS(SumRng, Array(Range("B2:B11"), 0, "A"), _
                               Array(Range("C2:C11"), 0, 10))
    Debug.Print SUMIFS(SumRng, Array(Range("B2:B11"), 0, "A"), _
                               Array(Range("C2:C11"), 0, 10), _
                               Array(Range("D2:D11"), 0, "Z"))
End Sub
```

The code works with the worksheet pictured below.

[image]